# How to integrate Maven, Jsf2, Liferay in eclipse

Tags: maven-2, jsf-2, liferay

I need help for integrate Maven 2, JSF 2 and liferay in eclipse.

can any body give perfact step to do it.?

Thanks ....

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You're very much more likely to get a useful answer if you ask a specific question. What are you having trouble doing?

Answer (score 0):

Best option for Liferay 6+ would be to download [Lferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide).

Or if you do not want to download another eclipse but use existing than you hav option to install Lifery IDE plugin.

In eclipse go to Help -> Eclipse marketplace ...
in Find box enter "liferay" and on "Liferay IDE" click Install.

Restart eclipse upon installation.

For maven go, again, to eclipse market place and enter "maven".

Install both "Maven integration for eclipse" and "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP".

Liferay IDE has support for creating JSF 2 portlets.

Comment: yes. but how project will be create. means when i will create maven project the will be there or not?  or when i will create liferay project the maven will be there or not? i want to integrate means i want making simple app using liferay , maven and jsf2.0.